# Не загружаются фото в медиатеку WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Не загружаются картинки в медиатеку, выдает ошибку "Обработка изображения не удалась. Если это фотография или большое изображение, пожалуйста, уменьшите его до 2500 пикселей и загрузите снова.". Хотя стоял плагин Imsanity, который должен был обрезать все фото до 1920px. На хостинге пробовала менять версию PHP и лимиты, вообще все возможные советы с нэта уже испробовала, все равно не работает. Вижу, что фото загружается в папку Uploads, но при этом в медиатеке его не видно даже после обновления страницы.
Если отключить все плагины, тоже выдает эту ошибку, но после обновления страницы показывает, что фото появилось в медиатеке.

Попробовала прописать следующий код в functions.php

```php
function wpb_image_editor_default_to_gd( $editors ) {
        $gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';
        $editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
        array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );
        return $editors;
    }
    add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', 'filter_choice_of_extension_612', 10, 4 );

    function filter_choice_of_extension_612( $threshold, $imagesize, $file, $attachment_id  ){
                $file_data_198 = getimagesize( $file );
                // choice of width and height limitation   // выбор своих параметров для картинки
                if ( $file_data_198[0] & 6000 || $file_data_198[1] & 6000 ) {
                    add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'wpb_image_editor_default_to_gd' );
                }
                return $threshold;
            }
    // filter stop scale IMAGE  // фильтр запрета создания scale изображений
    add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_zero' );
```

В таком случае если все плагины выключены, то картинка стала грузится нормально, без ошибок. Но только включаешь какой-то плагин, снова та же ошибка(

Как это исправить?

Comment: Выкинуть этот код и смотреть логи.

Answer (score 0):

может ресурсов не хватает на хостинге для отработки больших фото

попробуйте включить режим отладки в wp-config.php

define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE);

define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', TRUE);

и посмотреть в логах ошибки